# Setup ColumnDefinition and RowDefinition programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I would like to create a grid at run time. This is the xaml code to illustrate what I am looking for:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            Name='Test'>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height='*' />
        <RowDefinition Height='*' />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width='*' />
        <ColumnDefinition Width='*' />
        <ColumnDefinition Width='*' />
        <ColumnDefinition Width='*' />
        <ColumnDefinition Width='*' />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The xaml code above is fine except it is static and fixed. I would like the application to create the column and row definition at run time depending on user input. So, I created a method called initiate grid:

```
private void initiateGrid()
{
    int numberOfColumn = 10;
    for (int j = 0; j < (numberOfColumn / 5) + 1; j++)
    {
        RowDefinition r1 = new RowDefinition();
        Test.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumn; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            c1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            Test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.FontSize = 20;
            tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            tb.Text = string.Format("Text row {0}, column {1}", j, i);
            Test.Children.Add(tb);
            Grid.SetColumn(Test, i);
            Grid.SetRow(Test, j);
        }
    }
}
```

and I called it after I have initializeComponent in MainPage.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    initiateGrid();
}
```

I do not get compiler error nor run-time error but I do not see the textblock I attempted to populate to verify the accuracy of the positions.
Could someone shed some light for me? What was wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what was wrong in my code:

1. I created too many columns
2. I should have assigned the row and column to the textblocks, not the grid.

The correct code is as follows:

```
private void initiateGrid()
{
    int numberOfColumn = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumn; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            c1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            Test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
       }
    for (int j = 0; j < (numberOfColumn / 5) + 1; j++)
    {
        RowDefinition r1 = new RowDefinition();
        Test.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumn; i++)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.FontSize = 20;
            tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            tb.Text = string.Format("Text row {0}, column {1}", j, i);
            Test.Children.Add(tb);
            Grid.SetColumn(tb, i);
            Grid.SetRow(tb, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of exactly what you're trying to achieve using AttachedProperty https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/

and in your XAML you simply use like so:

XAML

```
<Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
      local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
```

ViewModel

```
    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        this.RowCount = 4;
        this.ColumnCount = 5;
    }

    private int _RowCount;

    public int RowCount
    {
        get { return _RowCount; }
        set { _RowCount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("RowCount"); }
    }

    private int _ColumnCount;

    public int ColumnCount
    {
        get { return _ColumnCount; }
        set { _ColumnCount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ColumnCount"); }
    }
```

Comment: The properties are view related - don't put them in the VM.

Comment: A view can have code in the code-behind file that results in the view model being assigned as its DataContext property. This could be as simple as a view instantiating a new view model and assigning it to its DataContext, or injecting a view model into a view using an inversion-of-control container.

However, connecting a view model to a view in a code-behind file is discouraged as it can cause problems for designers in both Visual Studio and Microsoft Expression Blend® design software.

Comment: Was that comment a reply to me? I'm confused - what exactly are you trying to say? It sounds like a quote from somewhere?

Comment: I'm well versed in MVVM. What exactly are you trying to say? Did you understand my comment? In case I wasn't clear, the `ColumnCount` and `RowCount` properties should be in the code bbehind of the view, not in the viewmodel. While you *can* put view related code in the VM, you *shouldn't*.

Comment: @Monty: The reference you gave me was great! I am still green with the dependency injection but I think I managed to compile it fine. However, the textblocks are still not showing. I have commented out Row and Column definitions accordingly in my method, just tagged on the textblock in each grid to make sure I see the layout. The only thing I deviated from your code is not using NotifyPropertyChanged but use UpdateLayout() instead for simplicity sake. I do not have a VM, so I put it in MainPage.xaml.cs just for testing sake. What is still not correct?